# App not available for your country

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I'm currently in my home country. I purchased my android mobile from the same, i.e. Huawei Mate 10 Lite.

I want to install an application (FOODPANDA) which is also available in my country but unable to do so. There appears a message "App not available for your country" and Play Stores does not allow me to install this app.

Your urgent piece of advice will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much.